# "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken"

Tags: django

I get this error

> Caught AssertionError while rendering: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

On this line

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
```

When I try to do this

```
copy_pickup_address = ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Address.objects.filter(shipment_pickup__user=user).order_by('-shipment_pickup__created')[:5])
```

But I need to slice it, because I only want the last 5 addresses. It renders fine, until I choose an address and submit the form. Why doesn't it like this? How can I get around it?

Comment: FYI, I was having other problems with using a `ModelChoiceField` too, so I just bypassed the issue by using a `ChoiceField` and grabbing the model manually... but I still don't know why I was getting this stupid error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The explanation is given at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/:

> even though slicing an unevaluated QuerySet returns another unevaluated QuerySet, modifying it further (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed, since that does not translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to solve your problem (seems you have already) but I think this is why you're getting the error: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/

> "Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be
>   sliced, using Python's array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated
>   QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will
>   execute the database query if you use the "step" parameter of slice
>   syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been
>   evaluated (partially or fully) also returns a list."

I guess you are forcing the queryset to be evaluated using the slice, so that further filtering results in an error?

Comment: That sounds like the opposite conclusion to draw from what you just quoted. "Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet" -- I'm not using the "step" parameter, so my query should still be unevaluated, no?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure... I'm the furthest thing from a Django expert, just wanted to offer that link so others might know where to dig deeper, I know some of the documentation is sometimes a bit tricky to find / recognize.

Comment: The current version of the documentation explains it: see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is what eventually worked for me

```
_latest_shipment_ids = [address.id for address in Address.objects.filter(shipment_pickup__user=user).order_by('-shipment_pickup__created')[:5]]
copy_pickup_address = ModelChoiceField(
    required=False,
    queryset=Address.objects.filter(
        shipment_pickup__user=user,
        id__in=_latest_shipment_ids
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten around a similar error by pulling my query-set out side of the code and then filtering it on the next line.

```
query = Address.objects.filter(shipment_pickup__user=user).order_by('-shipment_pickup__created')
copy_pickup_address = ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=query[:5])
```

Not sure if that'll work with your code.

Comment: Dunno.....but this problem is no longer relevant to me, so I'll just accept this and hopefully it'll work for someone else :) Or me..when I encounter it again down the road :\

Comment: I got that working several years ago, the way django is making these has probably changed since then.