# Slicing in django datatables

Tags: django, django-datatable

```
class OrderConsentsEnterpriseJson(BaseDatatableView):
    model = CONSENTS
    columns = ['iConsentID','iMSISDN','iCommID','iPurpose']
    order_columns = ['iConsentID','iMSISDN','iCommID','iPurpose']
    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        msisdn=9898989898
        EntityID=1
        resultset=CONSENTS.objects.filter(iStatus= settings.STATUS_FLAGS['Active'],iEntityID=EntityID,iMSISDN=int(msisdn)).order_by('-iConsentID')[:10]
        return resultset
    def render_column(self, row, column):
        if column == 'iPurpose':
            if row.iPurpose==1:
                return 'All'
            elif row.iPurpose==2:
                return 'Promotional'
            else:
                return 'Service'
        if column == 'iStatus':
            if row.iStatus==1:
                return 'Opted-in'
            elif row.iStatus==0:
                return 'Opted-out'
            else:
                return 'Expired'
        if column == 'iCommID':
            communication_mode=
             COMMUNICATION_MASTER.objects.filter(iCommID=row.iCommID).first()
            return communication_mode.vcCommunicationMode

        return super(OrderConsentsEnterpriseJson, self).render_column(row, column)
```

i want to get 10 records on page load.but i got the following error AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470111/cannot-filter-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken)

Comment: Do you try the exact query you posted?

Comment: yes,i have tried exactly

Comment: Without this [:10], is it ok?

Comment: yes,without slicing i am getting the resultset as desired

Comment: May be you apply any filter after slicing [:10]