# How to use slicing on queryset for django form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Let's say I have a django Model Player.  Player model has a filed name 'points' a integer field.
I need to show top 10 players ordered by points in from.ModelChoiceField.

The queryset would be

```
Player.objects.all().order_by('-points')[:10]
```

But if I use slicing on queryset which would be set into form field, it raises error when submit button is clicked.

```
Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

Any way to solve this?

Comment: This works just fine for me, and I tested across a virtually identical schema. Are there any other details that may be relevant?

Comment: You do have a typo in there. `-points` is `-poinst`, but unsure if that's in your actual code since you'd get a `FieldError` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470111/cannot-filter-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken)

But the answers there should clear stuff up for you

Taken from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/

> Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced,
>   using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet
>   usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute
>   the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax,
>   and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated
>   also returns a list.
>
> Also note that even though slicing an unevaluated QuerySet returns
>   another unevaluated QuerySet, modifying it further (e.g., adding more
>   filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed, since that does not
>   translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.