# Assertion Error cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two class in my models.py

```
class Icd(models.Model):
 code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=6)

class Icd10(models.Model):
 officialorder = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And also there are two viewsets for above models

```
class IcdViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Icd.objects.all()[:10]
 serializer_class = IcdSerializer

class Icd10ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Icd10.objects.all()[:10]
 serializer_class = Icd10Serializer
```

Below is my serializer

```
class IcdSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Icd
    fields = ['code']

class Icd10Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Icd10
    fields = ['officialorder']
```

And my app/urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', views.IcdViewSet)
router.register(r'icd10', views.Icd10ViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('icd/', include('app.urls')),
```

]

When i call localhost:8000/icd, i am getting correct response. When i call localhost:8000/icd/icd10, am getting below error

```
AssertionError at /icd/icd10/
Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/icd/icd10/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value:    
 Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

what needs to be changed to retrieve records from Icd10 models?

Comment: You question is duplicated and you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470111/cannot-filter-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken).

Comment: you can do some thing like this in `get_querysert()` and return from there.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

No-one has yet answered the "Why doesn't it like this?" part of your question. The explanation is given at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/:

```
even though slicing an unevaluated QuerySet returns another unevaluated QuerySet, modifying it further (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed, since that does not translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.
```

Comment: Am new to Django. any code to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did something wrong with the url, because it collided
you can do this

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', views.IcdViewSet, basename="icd")
router.register(r'icd10/add_urls', views.Icd10ViewSet, basename="icd10")
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls,"api"))
]
```

Comment: Only after adding some string after r'icd10'.Its working fine. Any reason for adding /add_urls after r'icd10 ?